# How to apply a filter before displaying active record value with ActionForm helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following form in my view (haml):

```
= form_for @app do |f|
  = f.text_field :app_value
```

My problem is I would like to pre-process @app.app_value before displaying it, and this is only for the view sake so I don't want to add another method in the model. For instance, `round_down(@app.app_value)`.

I could use the following to mimic what `f.text_field` does:

```
= text_field_tag("app_app_value", round_down(@app.app_value), name:app[app_value])
```

But is there a more Rails / elegant way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `f.text_field :app_value, value: round_down(@app.app_value)` instead of the `text_field_tag`.